# How to obtain project directory in a maven mojo?

Tags: maven-plugin

I'm trying to enclose some legacy code in a maven plugin. The legacy code is writing its outputs in the OS current working directory. I want to move all that into the target dir. I.e. if my project nesting is

```
A
-B
-C
```

and I run mvn install in B or C, I get the outputs in B or C and want to move them to B/target and C/target. Even worse, if I launch mvn install in A, outputs for both B and C wind up in A, which is obviously very bad (overwrites).

I've looked for a way to get the current project folder (not the place mvn install was launched from), but have found nothing so far that doesn't involve pushing this all back at the user (command line hacks, pom hacks, properties files, etc). I've also wished for a way to change the working directory before launching the legacy, but Java doesn't allow that. So how should I proceed?

Answer (score 9):

Just a quick note: for latest maven plugins, annotations could be used instead:

```
@Parameter(readonly = true, defaultValue = "${project}")
private MavenProject project;
```

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to work in Maven 3. Are there any ways to do this in Maven 3?

Comment: I am using latest maven and it works... Are you sure it is not something else ?

Comment: I got it to work, but I had to add a dependency on maven-project: `<groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId><artifactId>maven-project</artifactId><scope>provided</scope>`

Answer (score 8):

To answer my own question yet again (happens to me a lot), the solution starts here:

```
/**
 * The maven project.
 * 
 * @parameter expression="${project}"
 * @readonly
 */
private MavenProject project;
```

Then in a setup method:

```
this.model = project.getModel();
this.build = model.getBuild();
this.finalName = build.getFinalName();
this.targetDir = new File(build.getDirectory());
```

which gets *targetDir* pointing at the right place. Then the legacy code runs, dropping dots wherever it pleases and the plugin cleans up by MOVING them into target dir.

That was good enough for starters. But with targetDir available, I actually wound up toilet training the legacy code to do its business in the right place.

Comment: Where does `MavenProject` class come from?

Comment: @PawelVeselov from [maven-core](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven/maven-core)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to get the directory where the artifact is built it might be a bit neater to do this:

```
/**
 * @parameter expression="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}"
 * @readonly
 */
private File outputPath;
```